# Django: update_or_create repeated values being populated

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to update the fields of a model using update_or_create which is getting the data from an api. The problem is that all the fields are being populated with only the last two values from of i['Concessional] and i['Noncessional']

I'm using an external api to update the following model:

```
class Contributions(models.Model):
    trustee = models.ForeignKey(Trustee, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    concessional_caps = models.FloatField(null = True, blank = True)
    noncessional_caps = models.FloatField(null = True, blank = True)

    concessional_contributions_to_this_fund = models.FloatField(null = True, blank = True)
    non_concessional_contributions_to_this_fund = models.FloatField(null = True, blank = True)

    concessional_contributions_to_other_fund = models.FloatField(null = True, blank = True)
    non_concessional_contributions_to_other_fund = models.FloatField(null = True, blank = True)

    concessional_contributions_as_allocated =models.FloatField(null = True, blank = True)
    non_concessional_contributions_as_allocated = models.FloatField(null = True, blank = True)

    concessional_amounts_above_caps = models.FloatField(null = True, blank = True)
    non_concessional_amounts_above_caps = models.FloatField(null = True, blank = True)

    concessional_available_total = models.FloatField(null = True, blank = True)
    non_concessional_available_total = models.FloatField(null = True, blank = True)
```

Using the following code:

```
for i in range(len(contribution_caps_data['Data']['Members'])):
            Contributions.objects.update_or_create(trustee = Trustee.objects.get(trustee_name = contribution_caps_data['Data']['Members'][i]["Name"]))
            for j in contribution_caps_data['Data']['Members'][i]['YearBreakdown']['ContributionDetails']:
                Contributions.objects.update_or_create(trustee = Trustee.objects.get(trustee_name =  contribution_caps_data['Data']['Members'][i]["Name"]),
                    defaults = {
                    'concessional_caps': j['Concessional'],
                    'noncessional_caps': j['NonConcessional'],

                    'concessional_contributions_to_this_fund': j['Concessional'],
                    'non_concessional_contributions_to_this_fund': j['NonConcessional'],

                    'concessional_contributions_to_other_fund': j['Concessional'],
                    'non_concessional_contributions_as_allocated': j['NonConcessional'],

                    'concessional_contributions_as_allocated': j['Concessional'],
                    'non_concessional_amounts_above_caps': j['NonConcessional'],

                    'concessional_amounts_above_caps': j['Concessional'],
                    'non_concessional_amounts_above_caps': j['NonConcessional'],

                    'concessional_available_total': j['Concessional'],
                    'non_concessional_available_total': j['NonConcessional']
                    }

                    )
```

I am trying to create a new Contributions record, the first loop is to get the names(foreign key) and the second loop is to actually get the values of contributions

How would you recommend working around this. Should i be preprocessing into a usable form(maybe a dictionary) first and then updating the model. Forgive me for this being a trivial question, but I'm relatively new to Python and Django, but I cant seem to figure out the solution.

Answer (score 0):

- You never saved the data
- Model trustee: is `trustee_name` always guaranteed to get the instance? People can have the same name...
- likewise for the Contributions model - shouldn't there be some year or something attached to it?
- use variables and speaking variable names
- no `range(len(...` needed if you iterate over a list

Off the top of my head, this would be better

```
for member in contribution_caps_data['Data']['Members']:
    trustee, created = Trustee.objects.get_or_create(trustee_name=member['Name'])
    if created:
        trustee.save()

    for contribution_detail in member['YearBreakdown']['ContributionDetails']:
        # WARNING: you need to change this, otherwise you'll always get the same contribution for the trustee...
        # Perhaps there's the year in the YearBreakdown...
        contribution, created = Contributions.objects.get_or_create(trustee=trustee)  # gets same contribution in each iteration...

        contribution.concessional_caps = contribution_detail['Concessional']
        contribution.noncessional_caps = contribution_detail['NonConcessional']
        # ... the same for all other attributes ...

        contribution.save()
```